# How to read AcadDocument in AutoCAD LT 2022?

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin

Trying to migrate from AutoCAD 2020 to AutoCAD LT 2022, but it is unable to read AcadDocument and related functions. It's showing type or namespace could not be found.

using Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices;
using Autodesk.AutoCAD.Interop;
tried using this but does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AutoCAD LT versions prior to AutoCAD 2024 do not support any programmation. AutoCAD LT 2024 only supports AutoLISP/Visual LISP. To be able to use .NET programmation, you have to use a full AutoCAD.